# Appium timeout error while connecting to driver

Tags: android, selenium-webdriver, appium

I am using appium to automate native android application on real device but getting following exception at OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException
**The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub/session timed out after 60 seconds.**

On checking appium server the logs mentioned are as follows :

info: Console LogLevel: debug

> info: --> POST /wd/hub/session {"desiredCapabilities":{"device":"Android","platform":"Windows","deviceName":"Soti India (SM-P600)","platformName":"Android","platformVersion":"4.4","appPackage":"net.soti.hub","appActivity":"net.soti.securecontentlibrary.activities.SplashActivity"}}
>   info: Client User-Agent string: undefined
>   info: [debug] The following desired capabilities were provided, but not recognized by appium. They will be passed on to any other services running on this server. : device, platform
>   info: [debug] Didn't get app but did get Android package, will attempt to launch it on the device
>   info: [debug] Creating new appium session 0762641e-991f-4b4b-8953-e4b9135f22ef
>   info: Starting android appium
>   info: [debug] Getting Java version
>   info: Java version is: 1.8.0_45
>   info: [debug] Checking whether adb is present
>   warn: The ANDROID_HOME environment variable is not set to the Android SDK root directory path. ANDROID_HOME is required for compatibility with SDK 23+. Checking along PATH for adb.
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: where adb
>   info: [debug] Using adb from G:\adb\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
>
> warn: No app capability, can't parse package/activity
>   info: [debug] Set chromedriver binary as: C:\Appium\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\chromedriver\windows\chromedriver.exe
>   info: [debug] Using fast reset? true
>   info: [debug] Preparing device for session
>   info: [debug] Not checking whether app is present since we are assuming it's already on the device
>   info: Retrieving device
>   info: [debug] Trying to find a connected android device
>   info: [debug] Getting connected devices...
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: "G:\adb\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" devices
>   info: [debug] 1 device(s) connected
>   info: Found device 43007015586711f1
>   info: [debug] Setting device id to 43007015586711f1
>   info: [debug] Waiting for device to be ready and to respond to shell commands (timeout = 5)
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: "G:\adb\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s 43007015586711f1 wait-for-device
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: "G:\adb\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s 43007015586711f1 shell "echo 'ready'"
>   info: [debug] Starting logcat capture
>   error: Logcat capture failed: spawn ENOENT
>   info: [debug] Stopping logcat capture
>   info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session - - ms - -

What can be the possible issue

Comment: Is your ANDROID_HOME environment variable configured?

Comment: Yes environment path are set perfectly

Comment: you are using **platform:Windows**. Are you testing for window app? If you are testing for android app, your platform must be "Android". If you are testing for ios, your platform must be ios.

Comment: I got the same problem sporadically so i wonder if a higher timeout would help. But I just can't find any informations on that.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you have not configured android sdk path in your appium gui..

In your appium gui under android setting you have to set android sdk path

if your running appium from console then probably you have to set ANDROID_HOME in your environment variables and assign it your environment path

Comment: No. Got the same problem but sporadically — a clear indication that the setup is just fine and it is indeed a (to short) timeout.